# ubuntu 21.04 goes into emergency mode because it cannot mount /boot

Tags: boot, zfs

The full history is:

Ubuntu did not boot, I suspect due to full hard disk
I booted from usb
mounted zfs hard disk and deleted some files

to mount the hard disk i had to set a mountpoint (couldn't get it to work otherwise), and after that worked i restored it

then I booted again regularly, but it went into emergency mode.

I typed `journalctl -xb` to look at the logs, and there is one red line which says that it could not mount /boot. Before that it says:

> filesystem 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_' cannot be mounted, unable to open the dataset

(this is a windows dual boot system, in case it matters)

Answer (score -1):

managed to fix by

`fdisk -l | grep boot`
output helped me identify which device is my boot

then i zfs mounted it as bpool

then exited emergency mode and it booted correctly

after restart - still works